# Position fixed scroll bug

Tags: jquery, html, css

This my first post and it's already a question, sorry for that.

I'm working on a website for myself as promotion for further jobs after my apprenticeship.

If I open up the navigation, it slides in from the left, and a `::before` element darkens the content.

This only works correctly if I haven't scrolled down, otherwise it messes up the fixed elements and overlays.

Here is the site: http://mindinvader.de/impressum.html

Sorry for my bad english, I'm a german trainee.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll your left side part, your `content` div moves and it has `position:relative`. So the **backdrop** also moves.

When menu is opened, `.show-menu` gets added to body tag, being so the condition, 
add this css to CSS file.

```
.show-menu .content:before {position:fixed;}
```

Comment: and if you add `overflow:hidden` to your `.menu-button` as well, then that unwanted extra outline won't appear

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this:

```
.show-menu main {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```